# Box Trim has no effect

Tags: sculpting

I have recorded a [video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEyFAvftycs).

As one can see, the Box Trim sculpting has no effect in this case.

What might I be missing?

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your character is in Pose Position but should be in `Rest Position` to sculpt the mesh.

Select the `Armature` in the outliner, then select the `Object Data Properties` tab ("green running man" icon); look at the section "Skeleton", there switch to `Rest Position`.

[image: rest position (example)]

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why that is required?

Comment: @tmighty I don't know for sure but the armature deforms the mesh and most deforming tools need the mesh in its original form. If you switch to Edit mode then automatically the rest pose is selected. For some reason, this doesn't happen when you switch to the Sculp mode.